# Filter 'None' output Python using filter()

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am getting an error when trying to filter the 'None' output, when using the filter function in Python, here is my code:

```
def my_function(x):
if (x % 2 == 0):
    x=filter(None, x)
    return(x)

for x in range(1, 10):
    sum=sum+(my_function(x))
    print(sum)
```

and Python cannot make the sum as the None output cannot be removed, because it is "adding" this

```
None
2
None
4
None
6
None
8
None
```

and not this

```
2
4
6
8
```

Comment: think about what happens when your if condition is not true...

Answer (score 3):

Several errors here. First, don't use `sum` because is a builtin python function name.
The, `filter` expect an iterable to work with, and a function. `None` is not a function it will use the `identity` function (which returns the same value it takes) (tip by @bro-grammer). Since x is not an iterable you can't use filter on it.

You want to check if `x` is even:

```
def my_function(x):
    if (x % 2 == 0):
        return True
    return False

sumation = 0
for x in range(1, 10):
    if my_function(x):
        sumation += x
print(sumation)
```

The other option using actual `filter` and `sum` is :

```
>>> def my_function(x):
...     if (x % 2 == 0):
...         return True
...     return False
... 
>>> sumation = sum(filter(my_function, range(1, 10)))
>>> sumation
20
```

And the **pythonic** way of doing this is with a generator and `sum`:

```
>>> sum(x for x in range(1, 10) if x % 2 == 0 )
20
```

Comment: Though `filter` does require an iterable and a function to work, If `None` is passed as a function to `filter` it automatically assumes [identity function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function)!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're trying to use the filter function in a wrong way. You could use this as an example with this code:

```
def my_function(x):
    if (x % 2 == 0):
        return True
    else:
        return False

alist = filter(my_function,list(range(1,10)))
print(sum(alist))
```

Hope it helps